# FixedPage and Grid.IsSharedSizeScope

Tags: wpf, xps

I am trying to save an WPF UI to an XPS file stream.
Everything works as it should but there is one problem with Grid that use Grid.IsSharedSizeScope. Although when WPF UI rendered the column sizing is honored it is ignored when the UI saved to XPS so there is no equal column sizing.

Does anybody know why this could be happening and if there is a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application that generates various printed reports, which involves programmatically creating XAML controls and adding them to a FlowDocument. I remember hitting an issue where "Auto" widths are ignored, so had to use numeric or "star" values. Rendering the exact same XAML "to screen" worked fine.

Perhaps your shared size scope problem is related to the same problem. I remember reading about this "known issue" way back when I wrote this stuff, but don't have a link sorry.

I've just looked at my reporting code and didn't find anywhere that I've used shared size scopes (which is odd given their tabular nature), so perhaps I hit the same issue at the time.

Comment: Well i added this 

 view.Width = pageSize.Width;
 view.Measure(pageSize);

and it seem that it helped, still not sure if it would work 100% in all cases